# Comparing property of object with property of another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I am having difficulty comparing properties of two objects/arrays

**First object**

```
{
"62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d": {
    "selectedOption": 0
},
"62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e": {
    "selectedOption": 0
}}
```

**Second Array**

```
[
{
    "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d",
    "selected_ans": 0
},
{
    "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e",
    "selected_ans": 0
},
{
    "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586f",
    "ans": 0
}
```

]

Kindly suggest how to compare the initial property of first object(example: 62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d) with the question_id property of second array and return only the matching question_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) elements from `secondArr` using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as:

```js
const obj = {
    '62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d': {
        selectedOption: 0,
    },
    '62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e': {
        selectedOption: 0,
    },
};

const secondArr = [
    {
        question_id: '62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d',
        selected_ans: 0,
    },
    {
        question_id: '62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e',
        selected_ans: 0,
    },
    {
        question_id: '62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586f',
        ans: 0,
    },
];

const keys = new Set(Object.keys(obj));
const result = secondArr.filter((o) => keys.has(o.question_id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the find method defined on the array prototype.

```
function compare(id, arr){
    return arr.find(arrObj => arrObj.question_id === id);
}
```

To find all the matching ids from the object present in the array, you could loop through the keys and call the compare function for those keys like this.

```js
function compare(id, arr) {
    return arr.find(arrObj => arrObj.question_id === id);
}

const obj = {
    "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d": {
        "selectedOption": 0
    },
    "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e": {
        "selectedOption": 0
    }
}

const arr = [
    {
        "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586d",
        "selected_ans": 0
    },
    {
        "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586e",
        "selected_ans": 0
    },
    {
        "question_id": "62ac1c8d5b25ad28781a586f",
        "ans": 0
    }
]
const matchingObjects = [];
for (let key in obj) {
    const matchObject = compare(key, arr);
    if (matchObject) {
        matchingObjects.push(matchObject);
    }
}
console.log(matchingObjects);
```